# Why is the median of a PDF not always equal to the mean?

Tags: probability, probability-distribution-function

When studying probability density functions(PDFs), the focus is often placed on the "mean" and not the "median". The mean is often described as the center of mass of the PDF. I've always taken this as true.

However, the definition of the median seems to correspond to what I would consider the center of mass. That definition being:

$\int_{-\infty}^{median}pdf(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}$

Looking at this, we're essentially integrating the PDF until we reach the half-way point. To me, this seems identical to what we would consider the center of mass.

So why does integrating a PDF until we reach halfway (the median) not always equal the mean if the mean is the center of mass?

Note that I understand the difference between the mean and median from a general statistics perspective, but I'm curious from a PDF perspective.

I'll also format the question in the following manner:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}pdf(x)dx = mass$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x*pdf(x)dx = center\:of\:mass$

If we define the following equation:

$\int_{-\infty}^{T}pdf(x)dx = \frac{mass}{2}$

Why is T not always the center of mass? It appears T is the center of mass if the function is symmetric, but why doesn't it hold true if the function is non-symmetric?

Comment: Just take a look at the exponential distribution where the mean is not equal to the median

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

I don't have a rigorous proof, but as long as the PDF is symmetrical, the mean and median will be the same. When the PDF is asymmetrical, the mean and median will not be the same.

Comment: @Ben I can understand that the mean = median if the function is symmetric. However, I'm starting to think that I don't fully understand why the "center of mass" does not always equal the half-way point. I've updated my question to show my exact misunderstanding.

Comment: The definition of COM implies a weighted average (weighted by their mass) of the observations while the median is simply the "middle" of the distribution (you are not taking into account the "size" of the observations). By the way, if you define the COM as the mean of the distribution, the symmetry of the later does not ensure that COM=median (look for instance the Cauchy distribution)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because math is math, the median, mean, and mode don’t coincide in general. Intuition is personal and subjective. There is no objective way to judge an answer is correct or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider the pdf as defining the distribution of mass in a thin rod of infinite length and variable density (and so the "weight per inch" of the rod is different depending on which part of the rod we are talking about), then the mean is the point about which the rod is *perfectly balanced* (that is, if we set up a fulcrum and place the rod on it, it will be horizontal and balanced perfectly if the fulcrum is at the mean, and will tilt downwards on one side or the other if the fulcrum is anywhere else.

The median, on the other hand, is the point for which we can say that half the mass is to the left of the median and half the mass is to the right of the median. If that is what floats your boat as the one true and the only meaning of "center of mass" and you feel that everyone else who believes otherwise is in a state of mortal sin, so be it. Just be aware that when you refer to the median as the center of mass, you are likely to be misunderstood by those lesser mortals who have not attained your state of enlightenment and who still believe that *center of mass* is another name for what they call the *mean* of the pdf or random variable.

With respect to the comments on the main question as to an asymmetric pdf means that the mean and median will be different, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/237676/6633) over on stats.SE (where this question more properly belongs) gives an example of an asymmetric pdf for which the mean, median *and mode* all have the same value.

Comment: Very interesting pointers to stats.SE

Answer (score 2):

put a child on each side of a teeter totter that weigh the same.  The median is the middle. When the two are the same distance from the fulcrum, the system is balanced. One child moves further away from the fulcrum, the system will rotate in that direction. The median stayed the same, the center of gravity moved towards the child that moved farther away.

Another example  is the statistics of wealth in a place like Manhattan NYC. The presence of a relatively few billionaires relative to the more numerous middle and low income individuals, skews the mean income higher while the median is the more representative situation

Comment: Well, in your teeter-totter example, the median can be taken to be any point between the two equal-weight children (every point has the property that half the mass is to the left and half to the right), and if we take the midpoint between two equal masses as being _the_ median (why favor one child over the other by putting the median coset to it?), then the median has moved along with the mean.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Lets say it’s a very short teeter totter and the children are very fat

Comment: @Dilip : you may be assuming a teeter totter that can hold up two kids is massless, but I’ve never seen one of those in any playground.  Thus the median will stay at the original fulcrum point (unless one kids falls off or crosses to the other side)

Comment: @hotpaw2 No, the mass of the teeter-totter has nothing to do with the matter (assuming that the two sides have equal weight). The simplest model is that of two equal point masses for which the median can be taken to be _any_ point between the two masses; all such points have the property that half the mass is to the left of the point and half to the right. So which do we call the median? Stan says the median stays at the fulcrum while the mean moves toward the child further from the fulcrum but it is equally correct to say that the median also moved. Make the point masses into pdfs if you like

Comment: @DilipSarwate Agreed. The "median" in this case doesn't really make sense because you can choose any arbitrary point as long as it lies between each mass.

Comment: @Izzo  It makes as much sense as your question does.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In mundane terms:

- **the median is the place where you have the same total weight on the left and the right**
- **the mean is the place where you have a balance betwenn the left and the right**

A center of mass (aka barycenter or barycentre) takes into account a lever effect, or the location where the mass is applied.   Hence, the integrand $x\cdot p(x)$ under the integral sign.

The median in contrast does not really cares about where the mass are located. Hence the single  $p(x)$ integrand.

Both relate to a  class of ["momenta" (plural of momentum, or "moments"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)), that are values associated to "how a pdf is distributed" around a location, or shape factors, with various weighting of the locations. Classical (centered) moments write in the form:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-x_c)^M p(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

The $0$th moment  $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^0 p(x) \mathrm{d}x$  is equal to $1$ by definition. Each location $x$, affected by the $0$th power, becomes "location-less". The median cuts if in two equal parts. Same integral on each side, but not the same mass action. The latter is given by the  first raw moment (or expected value or mean)

$$m = \frac{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^1 p(x) \mathrm{d}x}{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^0 p(x) \mathrm{d}x}$$

and the first centeral moment is zero:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x^1-m_x) p(x) \mathrm{d}x=0$$